# How to get dbgrid cell value when you're typing? Delphi xe2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

The code below does not work due to the text being typing has not yet been saved:

```
DBGrid1.Columns [Col]. Field.AsString;
```

How could I get the text in the dbgrid and not directly from dataset?

The purpose of this is that I need to control what is being typed in real time.

I should not use:
 
onBeforePost.
OnValidate
onChange

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. It uses an inplace editor that is created internally when the column goes into edit mode and is freed immediately afterward. Controlling data entry in "real time" is usually a very poor idea from a usability standpoint for the users. There's probably a much better way to do your validation, but you didn't provide enough detail for me to suggest one.

Comment: Actually, "you can't" isn't quite true. You can create your own descendant of `TDBGrid`, and override it's `CreateEditor` to return your own editor implementation that will allow you to do whatever you want, and allow access to it externally. "You can't" refers to "using the standard TDBGrid", and should be "You can't, AFAICT, using the standard `TDBGrid`."

Comment: In this field I' already control typed keys... to accept only '0 .. 9 'and ','.

This field will accept 'n' phone numbers separated by commas. ex:

98004500,88004000,90450000

So I would like to restrict when user is typing....To avoid error like eg: two repeated commas or phones which have less than 8 characters.

Get it?

Comment: The proper way to control editing text in a database field is using the `TField.EditMask` property, or to use the `OnValidate` event. I "Get it", but trying to do it in the Column itself isn't going to work. :-) Let the user put whatever they want to in the field, and validate it at the proper time. If it's wrong, just don't let them post their changes until they've fixed the problem.

Comment: I got the cell value using:

TInPlaceEdit(dbGrid.Controls[0]).Text;


I already do validation on onBeforePost.

But I want a better way to interact with the user at the time of entering text.

I'll try a bit more here.